# Printer missing ink cartridge error - HP Officejet 6500 Wireless All-in-One Printer - E709n

Tags: printing, printer, ink, hp-officejet

I am not sure this is the correct forum to post this. However, I am currently using a HP Officejet 6500 Wireless All-in-One Printer - E709n. Recently, I discarded all of the color ink cartridges because they were empty. I went and bought an only black HP ink cartridge (as I most print documents).

I install the cartridge. However, the other spots are empty. 
The printer correctly identifies that my color cartridges are empty.

My problem is that the printer is stuck at this error; I cannot print. Would there be a way to override this error to only use the black cartridge? or would I need to purchase color cartridges?

Thanks

Comment: If you still have the empties, plug them back in.  There is a lot of residual ink that will dry and destroy the printhead and possibly the internal plumbing.  Once ink cartridges have been installed, they should not be removed for more than a brief period.  Even though you print only black documents, some amount of color is typically used for things like printing gray and smoothing edges.  These kinds of printers generally can't be set to operate with any cartridge missing.  (cont'd)

Comment: You might want to consider just getting a laser printer.  A full set of ink cartridges will cover most of the cost.  Even if you don't print enough color to use up the ink cartridges before they expire, you will still need to buy replacements, so a color inkjet doesn't sound like an economical solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the printer
With the printer turned on, disconnect the power cord from the printer. Unplug the power cord from the power source. Wait 60 seconds. Reconnect the power cord to a wall outlet and to the printer.

Regards,
James

Comment: Please quote a reference for this